# ClassCastException on Projection for repository method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, classcastexception

`java.lang.ClassCastException: au.com.parcelpoint.domain.batch.JobEntity cannot be cast to au.com.parcelpoint.domain.batch.projection.JobProjection`

The stack trace points to this line:

```
JobProjection jobProjection 
jobRepository.findSummaryByIdAndRetailerId(jobId, retailerId);
```

I am trying to reduce the fields needed in a simple projection for an actual persistence object. My projection object is called JobProjection and my persistence object is called JobEntity.

This is my JobProjection class:

```
@Projection(
        name = "jobProjection",
        types = { JobEntity.class })
public interface JobProjection {
    @Value("#{target.id}")
    Long getId();

    @Value("#{target.status}")
    JobEntity.Status getStatus();

    @Value("#{target.batches}")
    List<BatchEntity> getBatches();

    @Value("#{target.createdOn}")
    Date getCreatedOn();

    @Value("#{target.retailerId}")
    Long getRetailerId();
}
```

This is my JobRepository class (condensed):

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = JobProjection.class)
public interface JobRepository extends CrudRepository<JobEntity, Long>, JobCustom {
        JobProjection findSummaryByIdAndRetailerId(Long jobId, Long retailerId);
}
```

Comment: Why you need to have return type as **JobProjection** in this line
`JobProjection findSummaryByIdAndRetailerId(Long jobId, Long retailerId);`
It should be JobEntity right?
Your projection will be applied automatically through excerpt on top the result you get through repository.

Please See this example too :- Point 5 in link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts

Comment: The point of having the return type as a Projection rather than the actual persistence object is to access the limited form version of a persistence object. The other baeldung tutorial has the findBy"..." method's return type as the Projection rather than the actual hibernate persistence object.